# How to correctly use Docker to run eosio (including eosiocpp)?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code

I can get the basic quickstart working very easily but when I try to add smart contract I get  a lot of conflicts.

I have read an article here claiming - https://medium.com/@ekkis/eos-development-on-docker-3f4eb9b680ec (112 claps) -

> EOS provides a docker-compose.yml on their github repository, which is
>   great but isn’t specifically for developers i.e. tools like eosiocpp
>   aren’t included in the image.

I used the EOS docs - https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/Docker/README.md - and produced these containers -

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
a65fd706c24c        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/keos…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                                                           docker_keosd_1
3c1f3625ab25        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/node…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9876->9876/tcp   docker_nodeosd_1
```

I cannot get eosiocpp to work.

One issue for me is that the docs include docker-compose and then references are not to docker-compose.

I tried this -

```
alias eosiocpp='docker exec docker_keosd_1 /opt/eosio/bin/eosiocpp'
```

```
eosiocpp
```

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/eosio/bin/eosiocpp\": stat /opt/eosio/bin/eosiocpp: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I tried all kinds of combinations but everything produces some kind of error. I want to use docker because the source code installation took a long time when I tried that.

Can anyone provide to install and run eosio (with a smart contract) using docker?

Some details - I did an exec into the container -

```
cleos  data-dir  eosio-abigen  eosio-launcher  eosio-s2wasm  eosio-wast2wasm  keosd  nodeos  nodeosd.sh
root@nodeosd:/opt/eosio/bin# cd nodeos
bash: cd: nodeos: Not a directory
root@nodeosd:/opt/eosio/bin# exit
exit
trevor@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-lon1-01:~/eos/contracts/hello$ docker exec -ti docker_keosd_1 bash
root@keosd:/# ls
bin  boot  config.ini  contracts  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@keosd:/# cd opt
root@keosd:/opt# ls
eosio
root@keosd:/opt# cd eosio
root@keosd:/opt/eosio# ls
bin
root@keosd:/opt/eosio# cd bin
root@keosd:/opt/eosio/bin# ls
cleos  data-dir  eosio-abigen  eosio-launcher  eosio-s2wasm  eosio-wast2wasm  keosd  nodeos  nodeosd.sh
root@keosd:/opt/eosio/bin#
```

I cannot find eosiocpp in the /opt directory. Should it be there?

Comment: `eosiocpp` is deprecated and it was removed from the main repo briefly but it was added back very recently before it will be removed completely. perhaps you installed when `eosiocpp` was removed, but you should look for alternatives such as `eosio-cpp` binary